# Comparing two dataframes and getting the similarities as a new Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes d1 and d2 in python which have the same structure.
How can i compare them, and create a new dataframe d3 in which are only the rows, which are identical in both dataframes d1 and d2.

Comment: Use merge on all columns. if all column names are excatly the same, 'df3 = df1.merge(df2)' will work.

Comment: i dont want that d3 includes every row of d1 and d2. It should only include rows which are in d1 and also in d2.

Comment: This would do exactly as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Here

The merged df contains only common records (by subject id)

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data_a = {
    'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'],
    'last_name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman', 'Ali', 'Aoni', 'Atiches']}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_a, columns=['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])

raw_data_b = {
    'subject_id': ['4', '2', '6', '7', '8'],
    'first_name': ['Billy', 'Amy', 'Bran', 'Bryce', 'Betty'],
    'last_name': ['Bonder', 'Ackerman', 'Balwner', 'Brice', 'Btisan']}
df_b = pd.DataFrame(raw_data_b, columns=['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])

df_merge = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on='subject_id', how='inner')

print(df_merge)
```

output

```
 subject_id first_name_x last_name_x first_name_y last_name_y
0          2          Amy    Ackerman          Amy    Ackerman
1          4        Alice        Aoni        Billy      Bonder
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can i get the rows which are completly identical. For example lets say in df_b the first name for the id 2 is Papi and not Amy.

Comment: @user10027527 `df_merge = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=['subject_id','first_name','last_name'], how='inner')
`

Comment: Another option would be: `df_merge = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=None, how='inner')
`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MCVE of `merge`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(10,-1), columns = [*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])

    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
2  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
3  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
4  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
5  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
6  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
7  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
8  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
9  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20,120).reshape(10, -1), columns = [*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])

     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
0   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
1   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39
2   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49
3   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59
4   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69
5   70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79
6   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89
7   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99
8  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109
9  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119

df3 = df.merge(df2)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
1  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
2  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
3  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
4  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
5  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
6  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
7  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```