# Comparing 2 DataFrames and Get Similarity Based on Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames with different size rows.  I would like to compare and get the similarity between the two data frames based on two columns, category_id and size.  The results can go into a new data frame.  The columns will be equal lengths between the 2 data frames.

```
d1 = {'item_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'brand': ['E', 'E', 'E', 'E'],
      'category_id': [100, 100, 101, 100],
      'size': ['S', 'M', 'S', 'L'],
      'cost': [8.15, 12.91, 18.44, 14.95],
      'sell': [9.95, 14.49, 19.99, 16.79]
      }
      
d2 = {'item_id': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
      'brand': ['V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V', 'V'],
      'category_id': [100, 100, 102, 100, 101, 103],
      'size': ['S', 'M', 'XL', 'L', 'XS', 'XXL'],
      'cost': [9.29, 13.99, 8.44, 10.95, 11.79, 14.95],
      'sell': [10.95, 15.49, 12.99, 12.79, 13.69, 17.29]
      }
      
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df1
   item_id brand  category_id size   cost   sell
0        1     E          100    S   8.15   9.95
1        2     E          100    M  12.91  14.49
2        3     E          101    S  18.44  19.99
3        4     E          100    L  14.95  16.79

df2
   item_id brand  category_id size   cost   sell
0        5     V          100    S   9.29  10.95
1        6     V          100    M  13.99  15.49
2        7     V          102   XL   8.44  12.99
3        8     V          100    L  10.95  12.79
4        9     V          101   XS  11.79  13.69
5       10     V          103  XXL  14.95  17.29
```

Desire Output:

```
   item_id brand  category_id size   cost   sell
0        1     E          100    S   8.15   9.95
1        5     V          100    S   9.29  10.95
2        2     E          100    M  12.91  14.49
3        6     V          100    M  13.99  15.49
4        4     E          100    L  14.95  16.79
5        8     V          100    L  10.95  12.79
```

I've read many solutions that show the differences but not much when it comes to similarities.  I tried the code below but it just showed the similarity data from df1.

```
common_columns = df1.loc[:, df1.columns.isin(df2.columns)]
```

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56586398/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-similarities-as-a-new-dataframe) comes closest but it has equal row lengths so I don't think it will work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a double [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), once to get the common values, and once to select them out of the [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
cols = ['category_id', 'size']

common = df1[cols].drop_duplicates().merge(df2[cols].drop_duplicates())

out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).merge(common)
```

*NB. `drop_duplicates` is only needed if you can have duplicated combinations of category_id/size.*

Output:

```
   item_id brand  category_id size   cost   sell
0        1     E          100    S   8.15   9.95
1        5     V          100    S   9.29  10.95
2        2     E          100    M  12.91  14.49
3        6     V          100    M  13.99  15.49
4        4     E          100    L  14.95  16.79
5        8     V          100    L  10.95  12.79
```

Intermediate `common`:

```
   category_id size
0          100    S
1          100    M
2          100    L
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
def make_id_series(df):
    '''
     Function that retuns a series with an "id" concatenating 
    'category_id' and 'size' for comparison
    '''
    return df['category_id'].astype(str) + df['size'].astype(str)
```

Rows in df2 that are in df1, looking up by id created with make_id_series:

```
filtered_df2 = df2[(make_id_series(df2)).isin(make_id_series(df1))]
```

Rows in df1 that are in df2, looking up by id created with make_id_series:

```
filtered_df1 = df1[(make_id_series(df1)).isin(make_id_series(df2))]
```

Now you can concat both:

```
df_final = pd.concat(
    [filtered_df1, filtered_df2],
    axis=0,
    ignore_index=True
)
```